# How to append a escape character to the delimiter character within delimiter in unix

Tags: unix

How to append a escape character to  the delimiter character  within delimiter

example 
input:

```
|" rambo"s "|"1212"121"|
```

output:

```
|" rambo\"s "|"1212\"121"|
```

I would like to escape  double quotes

Comment: This feels like the XY problem - what are you trying to do that you need to escape these? Can you not use constructs like `<<< EOF`, `'...'`, or `$'...'`?

Comment: I would be reading the file via Informatica tool.
The current delimiter is |” .. but between the delimited columns we are receiving “ and it is creating an issue while reading the file. Hence thought of escaping the character “ by /“. So that I can read the file.

Comment: Not sure I understand the usage - an example would help, but in general if you're using the unix shell, you could quote the first string in your question as follows: `'|" rambo"s "|"1212"121"|'`